AWS CLI - How to attach IAM policy to SSO role?
Suppose:

a user X is managed in Azure AD and linked to an SSO role in AWS organization.
we want to give an IAM policy to access the DynamoDB in an AWS account A to the user X.

I created the IAM policy in the Account A because the DynamoDB is specific to the AWS account A. Then, how can attach the IAM policy to the SSO role for user X using AWS CLI?

You can't. AWS won't allow you to manually update the policy of SSO federated roles/users (obviously). You need to update the user's SSO role permission set from IAM Identity Center.
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name AWSReservedSSO_xxxxx_xxxxx --policy-arn <policy_arn>

An error occurred (UnmodifiableEntity) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation:
Cannot perform the operation on the protected role 'AWSReservedSSO_xxxxx_xxxxx' - this role is only modifiable by AWS

